# undefined method `initWithNibName'

Tags: ios, rubymotion

I have just started learning iOS development with RubyMotion and I'm doing this [tutorial](http://rubymotion-tutorial.com/10-api-driven-example/). It seems pretty easy to understand, but right now I'm stuck with this error I get when I run the `rake` command:

```
ColorController.rb:7:in `initWithColor:': undefined method `initWithNibName' for #<ColorController:0x9b4f470> (NoMethodError)
    from SearchController.rb:46:in `open_color:'
    from Color.rb:35:in `block in find:'
    from query.rb:358:in `call_delegator_with_response'
    from query.rb:128:in `connectionDidFinishLoading:'
```

I got to the part where `WHEW WELL THAT IS A TON OF CODE NOW ISN'T IT.` is found on the tutorial page and I'm stuck there. Currently my code looks like:

```
# app_delegate.rb
class AppDelegate
  def application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)
    @window = UIWindow.alloc.initWithFrame(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds)

    @search_controller = SearchController.alloc.initWithNibName(nil, bundle: nil)
    @navigation_controller = UINavigationController.alloc.initWithRootViewController(@search_controller)

    @window.rootViewController = @navigation_controller
    @window.makeKeyAndVisible
    true
  end
end

# ColorController.rb
class ColorController < UIViewController
  attr_accessor :color
  def initWithColor(color)
    initWithNibName(nil, bunlde: nil)
    self.color = color
    self
  end
  def viewDidLoad
    super
    self.title = self.color.hex

    @info_container = UIView.alloc.initWithFrame [[0, 0], [self.view.frame.size.width, 110]]
    @info_container.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor

    self.view.addSubview @info_container

    @color_view = UIView.alloc.initWithFrame [[10, 10], [90, 90]]
    @color_view.backgroundColor = String.new(self.color.hex).to_color

    self.view.addSubview @color_view

    @color_label = UILabel.alloc.initWithFrame [[110, 30], [0, 0]]
    @color_label.text = self.color.hex
    @color_label.sizeToFit

    self.view.addSubview @color_label

    @text_field = UITextField.alloc.initWithFrame [[110, 60], [100, 26]]
    @text_field.placeholder = "tag"
    @text_field.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft
    @text_field.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone
    @text_field.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect

    self.view.addSubview @text_field

    @add_button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonTypeRoundedRect)
    @add_button.setTitle("Add", forState: UIControlStateNormal)
    @add_button.setTitle("Adding", forState: UIControlStateDisabled)
    @add_button.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGrayColor, forState: UIControlStateDisabled)
    @add_button.sizeToFit
    @add_button.frame = [[@text_field.frame.origin.x + @text_field.frame.size.width + 10, @text_field.frame.origin.y], @add_button.frame.size]

    self.view.addSubview(@add_button)

    table_frame = [[0, @info_container.frame.size.height], [self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height - @info_container.frame.size.height - self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height]]
    @table_view = UITableView.alloc.initWithFrame(table_frame, style: UITableViewStylePlain)

    self.view.addSubview(@table_view)

  end
end

# SearchController.rb
class SearchController < UIViewController
def viewDidLoad
  super
  self.title = "Search"
  self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor

  @text_field = UITextField.alloc.initWithFrame [[10, 10], [self.view.frame.size.width - 20, 30]]
  @text_field.placeholder = "#abcabc"
  @text_field.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft
  @text_field.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone
  @text_field.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect
  @text_field.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2, self.view.frame.size.height / 2 - 100)

  self.view.addSubview @text_field

  @search_button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonTypeRoundedRect)
  @search_button.setTitle("Search", forState: UIControlStateNormal)
  @search_button.setTitle("Loading", forState: UIControlStateDisabled)
  @search_button.sizeToFit
  @search_button.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2, @text_field.center.y + 40)

  self.view.addSubview @search_button

  @search_button.when(UIControlEventTouchUpInside) do
    @search_button.enabled = false
    @text_field.enabled = false

    hex = @text_field.text
    hex = hex[1..-1] if hex[0] == "#"

    Color.find(hex) do |color|
      if color.nil?
        @search_button.setTitle("None :(", forState: UIControlStateNormal)
      else
        @search_button.setTitle("Search", forState: UIControlStateNormal)
        self.open_color(color)
      end
      @search_button.enabled = true
      @text_field.enabled = true
    end

  end

end
def open_color(color)
  self.navigationController.pushViewController(ColorController.alloc.initWithColor(color), animated: true)
end
end
```

I also have another two models which I'm sure they are not relevant unless you're going to run the code.

Can anyone tell me what am I supposed to do ? I realise that I'm trying to call the `initWithNibName` method which is not defined on my class, but that is what the tutorial does so I assumed it's correct. Do I need to define it on the `ColorController` class ? Or can I call it in some other way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just spelled bundle incorrectly.

change:

```
initWithNibName(nil, bunlde: nil)
```

to:

```
initWithNibName(nil, bundle: nil)
```

Comment: I'm an idiot ... it's some rubymine autocomplete that does that, it's not the first time. Do you have any advice on a better IDE for ruby that supports rubymotion and iOS SDK autocomplete ?

Comment: I would recommend sublime text with https://github.com/Watson1978/SublimeRubyMotionBuilder.

Comment: I have that, I really like it, I've been using it for building projects that involved html, js, css, but rubymine has more features that help ... And I cannot get the folders to stay in the side bar since I switched to Mac, each time I reopen it after I quit it, the folders are gone from the left side bar (in ST)